# Degree of covering map of manidolds alternative proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

For context, I am doing Hatcher's exercise 3.3.9, which aims to show if $p: M\to N$ is a finite sheeted covering map of two closed, connected orientable manifolds, then the degree of $p$ (as defined in Hatcher) matches the number of sheets of the cover (up to changing fundamental class to not deal with signs).

I know this is possible by summing local degrees (i.e using the previous exercise of Hatcher). I am wondering if this can be done using transfer maps.

My thought so far are as follows: Denote by $\tau: C_*(N)\to C_*(M)$ which sends a singular chain to the sum of its lifts. Then $\tau$ induces a map on homology $H_n(N)\to H_n(M)$, and we can see that $p\circ \tau$ is multiplication by $k$ the number of sheets of the cover. Each map individually is defined by $p_*([M])=a[N]$ and $\tau_*([N])=b[M]$, for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, and so we have $ab=k$, and we want to show $a=k$, this is thus equivalent to showing $b=1$. After this I don't really know if there is anything that can be done? I wasn't able to do any more than "setting the stage" for this theoretical alternative proof.

Thank youuu

Comment: What does "which sends a singular chain to the sum of its lifts" mean? Do you mean to associate to each singular simplex $\sigma$ in $N$ the chain of all singular simplices in $M$ lifting $\sigma$?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, yes that is what I mean, $\sigma\mapsto \sum_{i}\sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i: \Delta^k\to M$ is such that $p(\sigma_i)=\sigma$.